# Wordpress children comment style

Tags: css, wordpress, comments

I was able to give different comment background color for admin,author,registered user and guests in WordPress by using the following CSS.
however the children comments are also styled as same as the parent.
For example if a guest replies to a comment made by admin, then the reply is also same as the style of the comment made by admin.

```
.comment-details {
background: #E4E4E4;
}

.byuser .comment-details{
background: #CFCDFF;
}

.bypostauthor .comment-details{
background: #D3FFC5;
}

.comment-author-admin .comment-details{
background: #FFD3D3;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `background-color` property of the children to `transparent`?

Comment: do u mean like this

.children{
background-color:none;
}

Comment: if the children comments have a class called .children.

Comment: this is how my html is

http://pastebin.com/waAdCz4A

Comment: can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: I don't understand your html.  you've got all three classes (byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor) in the parent li element.  Could you please clarify what you're trying to do there?

Comment: ok please goto http://www.esfiya.com/backupfornewsite/6535 and try reply to a comment which is in green. please note that green means its a comment by author.